# JSon Result List save To DataBase MSSQL

Tags: c#, json, list, model

i have a json result list and i want save this items values to my MSSql Db. 
I try each loop objects and take values but sub items values not come. Any one help me ?

Hier is my class for json result and code behind.

Object Class For Json

```
 public class Price
    {
        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string currency { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("amount")]
        public float amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class TotalPrice
    {
        [JsonProperty("currency")]
        public string currency { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("amount")]
        public float amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class items
    {
        [JsonProperty("lineItemId")]
        public string lineItemId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("listingId")]
        public string listingId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("merchantId")]
        public string merchantId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("hbSku")]
        public string hbSku { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("merchantSku")]
        public string merchantSku { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public int quantity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public Price price { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("vat")]
        public double vat { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("totalPrice")]
        public TotalPrice totalPrice { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("cargoPaymentInfo")]
        public string cargoPaymentInfo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("properties")]
        public IList<object> properties { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("productName")]
        public string productName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("orderNumber")]
        public string orderNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("orderDate")]
        public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }

        public IList<items> item { get; set; }
    }

    public class Orders
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string status { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("customerId")]
        public string customerId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("orderDate")]
        public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("unpackedDate")]
        public object unpackedDate { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("barcode")]
        public string barcode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("packageNumber")]
        public string packageNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("shippingAddressDetail")]
        public string shippingAddressDetail { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("recipientName")]
        public string recipientName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("shippingCountryCode")]
        public string shippingCountryCode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("shippingDistrict")]
        public string shippingDistrict { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("shippingCity")]
        public string shippingCity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string email { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("phoneNumber")]
        public string phoneNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("companyName")]
        public string companyName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("billingAddress")]
        public string billingAddress { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("billingCity")]
        public string billingCity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("billingDistrict")]
        public string billingDistrict { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("taxOffice")]
        public string taxOffice { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("taxNumber")]
        public string taxNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("identityNo")]
        public string identityNo { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public IList<items> items { get; set; }
    }
```

And CodeBehind

```
 WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(link);
        req.Method = method;
        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(yetki));
        req.ContentType = "application/json";

         HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
         string result = "";

         using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
         {
              result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // do something fun...

             List<Orders> sip = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Orders>>(result);

             foreach(var item in sip)
             {
                 string id = item.id;
                 string status = item.status;
                 string barc = item.barcode;


             }
             List<items> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<items>>(result);
             foreach(var item in items)
             {
                 bar = item.merchantSku;
                 string on = item.orderNumber;

             }
             float fyt = 0;
             List<Price> prc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<Price >>(result);
             foreach(var f in prc)
             {
                 fyt = f.amount;
             }

            }
         }
```

So, how can i save this result to the DB :/ 
I doing to search 3-4 days and my mind stop

ps:First List run but Second List<> array return null values juste datetime come true vat and qnty return 0